# Add trailing slash for specific directory (Slim framework)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim, trailing-slash

**What I want to achieve:**

```
www.mydomain/app => www.mydomain/app/
```

Only for this url.

I'm using Slim Framework and this is how I handle my route:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app){
    // Some code goes here
});
```

---

**What I've tried:**

1) Any results with these:

```
$app->get('/?', function () use ($app){
    // Some code goes here
});

$app->get('(/)', function () use ($app){
    // Some code goes here
});
```

---

2) This one works great but brokes my other routes:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^app(/|$)
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+[^/]$ /$0/ [R=301,L]
```

For example I got route

```
www.mydomain.com/app/panel
```

after rules above it redirects me to

```
www.mydomain.com/panel/
```

---

3) This one also works but it adds slashes for every url:

```
# Add a trailing slash to any non-existent files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

---

4) This one redirects me to www.mydomain.com/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(app|foo|bar)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thank you for any guidance or references that might help me.

**UPDATE:**

My root directory .htaccess:

```
AddHandler php53 .php
Action php53 /cgi-bin/php53.cgi


DirectoryIndex index.php
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_HOST}  !^192\..*
#RewriteRule   ^(.*)         http://www.randomurl.com/$1 [R,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rqp=$1 [L,QSA]
php_flag last_modified 1
php_flag register_globals 0
php_flag display_errors 1
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1

php_flag error_reporting E_ALL

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#AddType  text/html .d

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .dll
```

My app directory .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If all you want is this `www.mydomain/app => www.mydomain/app/`

Then you can just add this line in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htacces`:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

as the first line in your root `.htaccess`

Comment: Works for www.mydomain/app => www.mydomain/app/. But I get 404 on www.mydomain/app/panel.

Comment: As you can see that pattern `^(app)$` won't match `/app/panel` hence it won't cause 404. Does `/app/panel` work without this rule?

Comment: In order other urls to work properly these rules are defined:                                                      **RewriteEngine On                                                                  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]          **                                                                 But then your rule stops working.

Comment: Your rule goes first as you said. Still doesn't work. .htaccess file is located inside app directory and it is only one in it. Though one more .htaccess is located at parent directory (root) => www.mydomain.com/

Comment: Oh Ok in that case my suggested rule goes as **first rule in parent directory of `app`**

Comment: Now I got 400 Bad Request for => www.mydomain/app. Everything else works good.

Comment: Is app a real directory?

Comment: Yes. 'app' is a real directory. Directory contains index.php with my app code.

Comment: ok check the update and make sure it is in the parent .htaccess of app

Comment: If I add 'DirectorySlash On' in my root .htaccess on every page including main page (www.mydomain.com) I'm getting 500 error

Comment: Hmm `DirectorySlash` must always be `On` for security reasons also. Why it is giving 500 error to you difficult to guess. Can you check your Apache error.log for the reason of this error. Also it would help immensely if you post both root .htaccess and `/app/.htaccess` in your question.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE. Meanwhile I'll look for apache error logs.

Comment: Ok add this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` below `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in your `app/.htaccess` and retest.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Just a request about your future question to provide as much details about your current rules and current setup upfront to get best possible answers.